# Query Multiplies The Result When Selecting For One Value

Tags: sql, oracle, select, subquery

###### Hello, I want to show Product, Sub Materials,Alternatives, Orders and Dates. Product has 5 sub materials and 8 orders in different dates. The problem I am facing is that Sub Materials multiplies 8 times according to orders. How can I fetch data properly for one repeated value? Thank you for your support.

###### -Query is as follows

```
SELECT 
      B.BOMREC_CODE AS PRODUCT_CODE,
      S.NAME AS PRODUCT_NAME,
      B.BOMREC_MATERIALCODE AS SUB_MATERIAL,
      S1.NAME AS SUB_MATERIAL_NAME,
      B.BOMREC_ALTCODE AS ALTERNATIVE,
      (SIP.SF_QUANTITY - SIP.SF_NEWSHIPPED) AS OPEN_ORDERQT
      SIP.DLVDATE AS DELIERY_DATE
FROM BOMU01T B
LEFT JOIN STOCK00 S ON TRIM(S.CODE)=TRIM(B.BOMREC_CODE) 
LEFT JOIN STOCK00 S1 ON TRIM(S1.CODE)=TRIM(B.BOMREC_MATERIALCODE)
LEFT JOIN STOCK40T SIP ON TRIM(SIP.CODE)=TRIM(B.BOMREC_CODE)
WHERE B.BOMREC_CODE='2496802300'
ORDER BY 1 DESC
```

[image]

##### -STOCK00 Table holds the Product's name

##### -STOCK40T Table holds the orders. When I search the orders for '2496802300' it shows as below

[image]

##### -What I want should look like this

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your missing a Group by clause

Try This:

```
SELECT 
      B.BOMREC_CODE AS PRODUCT_CODE,
      S.NAME AS PRODUCT_NAME,
      B.BOMREC_MATERIALCODE AS SUB_MATERIAL,
      S.NAME AS SUB_MATERIAL_NAME,
      B.BOMREC_ALTCODE AS ALTERNATIVE,
      (SIP.SF_QUANTITY - SIP.SF_NEWSHIPPED) AS OPEN_ORDERQT
      SIP.DLVDATE AS DELIERY_DATE
FROM BOMU01T B
LEFT JOIN STOCK00 S ON TRIM(B.BOMREC_CODE)= TRIM(S.CODE) 
AND TRIM(B.BOMREC_MATERIALCODE)=TRIM(S.CODE)
LEFT JOIN STOCK40T SIP ON TRIM(B.BOMREC_CODE)=TRIM(SIP.CODE)
WHERE B.BOMREC_CODE='2496802300'   

ORDER BY 7 DESC;
```

Comment: Hello, no I tried this. Nothings changed.

Comment: @Ksaxes Updated query to sort the DELIVERY_DATE column.

Comment: @Ksaxes also your LEFT JOIN appears to be duplicated.:                              
'LEFT JOIN STOCK00 S ON TRIM(S.CODE)=TRIM(B.BOMREC_CODE) '
'LEFT JOIN STOCK00 S1 ON TRIM(S1.CODE)=TRIM(B.BOMREC_MATERIALCODE)'

Comment: I assume you only have three tables you are trying to join: BOMU01T, STOCK00, STOCK40T.  If yes, The second LEFT JOIN statement is redundant and should be switch to an AND operator.  Updated the answer to reflect this.

Comment: I found the problem. 'Order by' somehow was not working properly. Now I get the result like I wanted. Thank you for your help.

Comment: No problem, glad the ORDER BY column fix worked for you.